# Cloud Code Not Updating User's Username Properly

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

For some reason Cloud Code isn't updating the current user's username, even though it is updating the email field. I'm using the master key, and although everything returns success, the username doesn't update (even on the data browser).

Here's my code:

```
        //Get Current User
        var user = Parse.User.current();

        //Update username
        user.set("email", request.params.email);
        user.set("username", request.params.username);
        user.save(null, {

                      //Success
                      success: function(user) {

                        //Done
                        response.success("Username saved! ");
                      },

                      //Error
                      error: function(user, error) {

                        // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
                        response.error("Aww man. Something went wrong. Please try again. ");
                      }

        });
```

I've made sure that the parameters are being passed correctly, and that there isn't a mistake with the name etc on my iOS app.

Comment: I get the logged-in user making the request in the cloud with request.user.

Comment: you have not explicitly shown your self using the master key in this code. Im assuming its because of a typo?

Comment: @VarunAgarwal the master key shouldn't be necessary since the requesting user is only modifying their own data right? I believe the master key would only be necessary if you were trying to modify someone else's data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that there is an issue with getting the calling user.

Use `request.user` to get the calling user and try the following.

```
// Get the requesting user
var user = request.user;

if (user) {
    user.set("email", request.params.email);
    user.set("username", request.params.username);
    user.save(null, {
        success: function(user) {
            response.success("Username saved! ");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
} else {
    response.error("Aww man. Something went wrong. Please try again. ");
}
```

Comment: Changing the way I set the user from `Parse.User.current();` to `request.user;` seemed to solve it. That's strange since the documentation uses both. Thank you Russell.